# Connection between interpretation, variable assignment and truth valuation.

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Let us have some formal language $\mathcal{L}$ and an $\mathcal{L}$-structure $\mathcal{U}=(A,\mathcal{I})$. Where $A$ - non-empty set, called domain, and $\mathcal{I}$ - interpretation.

I know that **interpretation** is a function (or family of functions) that assigns to every constant, functional or predicative symbol from the signature of the language $\mathcal{L}$ correspondent elements, functions and relations on the domain $A$.

Also, I know that there exists some function $\mu : T \to A$ called **variable assignment** that associates every (variable) term of the language $\mathcal{L}$ to the element of domain $A$.

**Question 1:** Where does this function $\mu$ belong? Is it the part of the structure $\mathcal{U}$ or interpretation $\mathcal{I}$ ? Or is it part of a formal language? As it is dependent on a domain, why it is not included in the definition of a structure $\mathcal{U}$?

Then, if we want to assign "truth-values" to every sentence of our language $\mathcal{L}$, we need to specify a so-called **object of truth values** $\Omega$ and a **truth-valuation function** $V:\Phi\to \Omega$ (where $\Phi$ is a set of all sentences of $\mathcal{L}$).

**Question 2:** Similar to the first. Does this $\Omega$ or $V$ has anything to do with the domain $A$ or interpretation $\mathcal{I}$ of the structure $\mathcal{U}$, or with variable assignment function $\mu$? Or they are purely independently defined objects? I thought that assignment of truth-values should be dependent on the structure in which we want to interpret our language, (for example, I thought that $\Omega$ might be an element or a subset of $A$) but I do not clearly see the connection between those notions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *interpretation* $\mathcal I$ is a function from the set of *symbols* of the language to "objects of the world", i.e. to elements of the domain $A$ or of its power-set.

In the same way, a *variable assignment* function $\mu$ is a function from a subset of *symbols* of the language, i.e. the set of *variables* to the domain $A$, i.e.:

> $\mu : \text{Var} \to A$.

The *variable assignment* function "trick" is used to handle open formulas, like e.g. $(x=0)$.

How can we determine the truth-value of $(x=0)$ in the structure $\mathbb N$ ? It depends on what $x$ refers to.

A free var in a formula acts as a pronoun; when I assert "it is red", the truth value of my assertion will depend on what "it" refers to: if it refers to my car, the statement asserted is *false*, if it refers to my pen, it is *true*.

In the same way, the interpretation will define the denotation of the *constant* $0$: the number **zero**.

With a variable assignment function $\mu$ such that $\mu(x)=0$ we have that the formula $(x=0)$ is satisfied in $\mathbb N$ **with** the variable assigment fucntion $\mu$, i.e.

> $\mathbb N, \mu \vDash (x=0)$.

With e.g. a different function $\mu'$ such that $\mu'(x)=1$, obviously the above formula is not satisfied.

More formally, for an *atomic* formula $x=c$, with $c$ an individual *constant*, we have that it is satisfied in $\mathcal A$ with $\mu$ (i.e. $\mathcal A, \mu \vDash (x=c)$) iff the element of $A$ (domain of $\mathcal A$) assigned to $c$ as referent, call it $c^A$, is the same element assigned to $x$ by $\mu$, i.e. $μ(x)=c^A$.

In conclusion, the interpretation and a variable assignment function determine univocally a truth value for every formula of the language. If the formula is a closed one (i.e. a *sentence*) its truth value does not depends on the variable assignment.

Comment: Thanks! How do we formally define if our formula "is satisfied"? I think we must somehow formally "assign" some truth-value to it. But how specifically is this assignation done? Also, what if I want to have not only "TRUE" and "FALSE" values, but few others too?

Comment: @SergeyDylda - the formula $\varphi(x)$ is *satisfied* in the interpretation $\mathcal A$ with var assignment $\mu$ (in symbols: $\mathcal A, \mu \vDash \varphi(x)$) **iff** ... several clauses. Example: if $\varphi(x)$ is the atomic formula $x=c$ with $c$ individual *constant*, it is satisfied iff the element of $A$ (domain of $\mathcal A$) assigned to $c$ as referent, call it $c^A$, is the same element assigned to $x$ by $\mu$, i.e. $\mu(x)=c^A$.